# No TM Grammar registered for this language

Tags: visual-studio-code

What causes the error "No TM Grammar registered for this language" when creating / debugging your own custom syntax in VS Code?

Answer (score 5):

For me it was that the `contributes.languages.id` property of `package.json` needs to match the `name` property in the `tmLanguage.json` file. Also, the `contributes.grammars.scopeName` of `package.json` needs to match the `scopeName` of the `tmLanguage.json` file.

Answer (score 3):

I hit this problem as a result of defining the grammar in YAML and using js-yaml to translate it, per the VSCode extension docs suggestion.  It looks like js-yaml outputs in UTF-16 LE, which is loaded just fine by the VSCode editor, but the VSCode TextMate grammar parser doesn't support.

Clicking the encoding at the bottom right of VSCode and saving it as UTF-8 fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Validate your tmlanguage.json file.
Invalid json files are not loaded and registered.

Answer (score 1):

For me, my tmLanguage.json file was in UTF8+BOM format, which VSCode seems to (silently) not like. Changing it to normal UTF8 format fixed it.